# Taking a limit for a modified difference quotient without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This limit is immediate using L'Hopital rule:

$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}  \frac{f\big(x + h(\alpha - x)\big) - f(x)}{h}=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}  f'\big(x + h(\alpha - x)\big) (\alpha - x)=
 f'(x) (\alpha - x)\\
$$

Anyway I wonder if it can be equally simple to solve it without L'Hopital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the MVT
$$\frac{f\big(x + h(\alpha - x)\big) - f(x)}{h}=f'(x_h)(\alpha - x)$$
with $x_h$ between $x$ and $x+h(\alpha - x)$.

In the second equality, you are supposing thaf $f'$ is continuous. With this hypothesis:
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f\big(x + h(\alpha - x)\big) - f(x)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to 0} f'(x_h)(\alpha - x)=f'(\lim_{h\to 0} x_h)(\alpha - x)=
f'(x)(\alpha - x).
$$